# ¿Cómo guardar puntos (x,y) cartesianos de un archivo en listas en C?

Tags: c

Estoy estudiando listas y estoy haciendo un ejercicio donde debo sacar puntos cartesianos (X,Y) de un archivo en C para luego guardar todas las coordenadas X en una lista y todas las Y en otra lista para luego sacare el valor máximo de cada una de ellas. Cómo no me manejo bien con archivos aún no lo he podido resolver del todo.
Por ejemplo si tengo un archivo de la forma:

```
2,3 
3,1 
1,4
```

lo que quiero obtener es:

```
listaX = {2,3,1};
listaY = {3,1,4};
```

Como aun no domino lo básico me esta costando más de lo que debería. Dejo mi código.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PUNTOS    3 //Son tres puntos en el archivo.
#define MAXC 1024

int main(){
char buf[MAXC];
FILE *datos;
int listax[PUNTOS] = {0,0,0};
int listay[PUNTOS] = {0,0,0};
datos = fopen("example.txt","r");
while(fgets(buf,MAXC,datos)){
    int x;
    int y;
    if(sscanf(buf, "%d,%d", &x, &y)!=2){
        continue;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < PUNTOS; ++i)
    {
        listax[i]=x;
    }   
}
fclose(datos);
printf("%d\n",listax[0] );
printf("%d\n",listax[1] );
printf("%d\n",listax[2] );
return 0;
}
```

que me imprime puros 1's. Según yo el error es la forma en que almaceno X en la lista. (estoy intentando solo con X pero deberia ser para ambas x e y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salen puros unos porque el for rellena toda la listax cada vez que lee una nueva linea del archivo, y como el 1 es la ultima linea eso es lo que imprime.
Hay que quitar el for para que funcione:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define PUNTOS 3 //Son tres puntos en el archivo.
#define MAXC 1024

int main(){
    char buf[MAXC];
    FILE *datos;
    int listax[PUNTOS] = {0,0,0};
    int listay[PUNTOS] = {0,0,0};
    datos = fopen("example.txt","r");
    int i=0;
    while(fgets(buf,MAXC,datos) && i < PUNTOS){
        int x;
        int y;
        if(sscanf(buf, "%d,%d", &x, &y)!=2){
            continue;
        }
        listax[i]=x;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(datos);
    printf("%d\n",listax[0] );
    printf("%d\n",listax[1] );
    printf("%d\n",listax[2] );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Que torpe de mi parte, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

tomando de ejemplo la respuesta anterior entregada por "Carlos", y para complementar la forma de lectura, con dimensionado dimamico, puedes usar un modelo como este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXC 1024

int main(){
    char buf[MAXC];
    FILE *datos;
    int  *listax;
    int  *listay;

    if ((datos=fopen("example.txt","r"))==NULL){
       printf("No se pudo leer archivo 'example.txt'\n");
       return 1;
    }

    int i=0;
    while(fgets(buf,MAXC,datos)){
        int x;
        int y;
        if(sscanf(buf, "%d,%d", &x, &y)!=2){
            continue;
        }
        i++;
        listax=(int*)realloc(listax,sizeof(int)*i);
        listay=(int*)realloc(listay,sizeof(int)*i);

        listax[i-1]=x;
        listay[i-1]=y;
    }
    fclose(datos);
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("x->%d , y->%d\n",listax[j],listay[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```